# Flutter hive box not found even though it was opened

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I'm building a flutter app with Hive and I can't solve the error '`Box not found. Did you forget to call Hive.openBox()?`'.
My main method is this:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   Hive
    ..initFlutter()
    ..registerAdapter(CountedAdapter())
    ..openBox<Counted>('counters');
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I also set up the typeadapter for my Counted class and it's definitely correct because I used it before. I created a class called DataManager for easier access:

```dart
class DataManager{
  static Box<Counted> getCounters()=>Hive.box<Counted>('counters');
}
```

I'm trying to use in a ValueListenableBuilder but I get this error again and again. How could I solve it?
This is my Home widget where I want to use it.

```dart
import 'package:counter/manager/datamanager.dart';
import 'package:counter/model/counted.dart';
import 'package:fab_circular_menu/fab_circular_menu.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  static const route = '/';

  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      minimum: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: FabCircularMenu(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.plus),
              ),
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.trash)),
            ],
            animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            ringDiameter: 300,
            ringColor: Colors.teal,
          ),
          body: ValueListenableBuilder<Box<Counted>>(
            valueListenable: DataManager.getCounters().listenable(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, box, _) {
              if (!box.isOpen || box.isEmpty) {
                return const Center(
                    child: Text('No counter found. Create and save one.'));
              }
              final list = box.values.toList().cast<Counted>();
              return ListView(
                children: List.generate(box.values.length, (i) {
                  return SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                    child: Text(list[i].name.toString()),
                  );
                }),
              );
            },
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Btw I also tried to await the `openBox()` method but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

the `Hive`'s `initFlutter()` and `openBox()` methods is asynchronous, opening a box takes some time, so you can't call that box when it's not opened yet, so you need to change your `main()` to this:

```
 Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Hive.initFlutter();
    Hive.registerAdapter(CountedAdapter());
    await Hive.openBox<Counted>('counters'); // wait until the box is opened.
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you really use a `FutureBuilder` in your UI instead?

Comment: no, you don't need to since there is no snapshot that you will use immediately when got from that Future, it only opens that box only one time, then you can use it synchronously with your other widgets, screens.

Comment: https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/README?id=open-a-box

Comment: As the `.openBox` method is async, it could cause a delay on opening the app to first seeing any rendered UI no? So use `Future.wait([Hive.openBox(..)])` and pass that to `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: Future.wait() is used to run multiple Futures in parallel at the same time, right? , using it with only one Future is the same as calling it with a regular await.

Comment: can I ask why we need a FutureBuilder ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe @Gwhyyy is right in that the cause is due to `Hive.openBox()` being an async method, so it needs to be `await`ed before accessing the box, however calling `await Hive.openBox()` in your `main` method could cause some lag between opening your application and seeing anything rendered to the screen. This could happen if your box is particularly large, and reading the data in from storage could take a while.

For this reason, it might be worth using a `FutureBuilder` to wait instead. This way your UI can render and be responsive immediately.

In the code below, a circular spinner will display while the `Hive.openBox` method is running, and after its finished a `MainScreen()` widget will then be displayed.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {/* ... */}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future _boxLoadFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _boxLoadFuture = Future.wait([Hive.openBox('counters')]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: _boxLoadFuture,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            // while waiting for `Hive.openBox()` to finish
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              // if `Hive.openBox()` threw an error
              return Center(child: Text('Error:\n\n ${snapshot.error}'));
            } else {
              // success, continue with app
              return MainScreen();
            }
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Totally worth reading.

Comment: I have one note about this and correct me if I'm wrong, using FutureBuilder with a future that's initialized only one time in the initState() will prevent it from updating it's state every time right ?

Comment: so if I call setState(() {}) the FutureBuilder will not be updated, right ?

Comment: Flutter MaterialApp contains some inheritedWidgets like MediaQuery, Theme, Navigator..., If at some point in my app I want to change the Theme of the entire app and I decided to call a SetState to change the Theme, or by using some state management tools like provider.

Comment: will it's state be updated if we FutureBuilder cannot be updated because its Future is initialized only once ?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. `FutureBuilder` will rebuild if `setState()` is called for example. See this [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1) to see it in action :)

Comment: I tried you're sample of code, but I found that also Hive.initFlutter is asynchronous and needs to wait it takes also time, I tried to add it inside Future.wait() and an error is thrown because we can't open a box until Hive is initialized

Comment: I corrected it on my answer